# Клиент не передает сообщения серверу

Tags: java, сокет

Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема - клиент подключается, но не передает данные на сервер ? (В логах пусто)
Клиент и сервер находятся на одном хосте, при подлючении по telnet сообщения доставляются.

Сервер сокет:

```
public class Server extends Thread {

private ServerSocket socket;
private static int PORT = 5678;

public Server () {
    this(PORT);
}

public Server (int p) {
    int PORT = p;
    setServerPort(PORT);
}

private void setServerPort(int p) {
    Server.PORT = p;
}

public ServerSocket getServerSocket() {
    return this.socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        this.socket = socket;

        System.out.println("Sever running at port: " + PORT);
        while (true) {
            Socket accept = socket.accept();
            new ServeOneClient(accept);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Сервер-клиенты:

```
public class ServeOneClient extends Thread {

private Socket socket;
private OutputStreamWriter out;
private BufferedReader in;

public ServeOneClient (Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    System.out.println("Client connected: " + socket.toString());
    this.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {

        try {
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));            
            System.out.println(" Line + " + in.readLine());

        } catch (IOException s) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Client connection closed " + socket.toString());
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
            }

            s.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Код клиента :

```
public class Client extends Thread {

private Socket connect;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

private String address;
private int port;

public Client(String a, int p) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    address = a;
    port = p;
}

private void setConnect (Socket c) {
    this.connect = c;
}

private void setOOS (ObjectOutputStream output) {
    this.output = output;
}

private void setOIS (ObjectInputStream input) {
    this.input = input;
}

public String getServerAddress () {
    return this.address;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        while(true) {

            Socket connect = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(address), port);
            setConnect (connect);

            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
            setOOS (output);

            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
            setOIS (input);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMsg(String msg) {

    try {
        output.writeObject(connect.getPort() + ": " + msg);
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Запуск клиента:

```
Client c = new Client(Preferences.getTwinAddress(), 5678);
c.start();
//данный вызов не дает результат.               
c.sendMsg("CUSTOM MESSAGE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий клиент:

```
public class Client extends Thread {

private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader input;
private PrintWriter output;

public Client(String addr, int port) {

    try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(addr), port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Socket failed");
    }
    try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

        start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            System.err.println("Socket not closed");
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            if(RunApplication.getMsg() != null) {
                output.println("Client " + ": " + RunApplication.getMsg());
                RunApplication.setMsg(null);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Socket not closed");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Хорошая статья [тут](http://javatutor.net/books/tiej/socket) )